# How to use Pipe Symbol through exec in Java

Tags: java, exec, pipe

I am using the following code to get the details of all process running in the system:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps aux");
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

I want to filter `ps aux` down with the pipe symbol so I use this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps aux | grep java");
```

It goes to the ErrorStream. Later I noticed the Pipe Symbol (|) is used as Bitwise inclusive OR operator in Java. So I used backslash in front of pipe symbol as shown below:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps aux \\| grep java");
```

But again it goes to the ErrorStream.  How can I run `ps aux | grep java` through exec in Java?

Comment: Just to clarify, the bitwise OR operator `|` is not interpreted within strings so you shouldn't need to escape it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pipe is a shell feature - you're not using a shell, you're exec'ing a process (`ps`).

But really, why would you want to do this? What you're saying is:

"execute ps, then pipe its output to another program (grep) and have it extract what I need"

You just need to extract what you want from the output of `ps`. Use a `Matcher` and only pay attention to the lines that include `java` from your `InputStream`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When i use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps aux") it takes time to process all lines from InputStream. So i thought Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps aux | grep java") will simply my work. If i go with Matcher again it will take time to process lines. Is there any other way to use pipe?

Comment: It really shouldn't take much more time for you to process the lines with a `Matcher` than a shell having to exec another process and pipe the output of `ps` to it. That being said ... I *think* you could exec a shell such as `/bin/bash -c ps aux |grep java`

Answer (score 17):

Well, if you want to use pipes in the Process you exec, then you need to start a shell like bash, and give ps and grep on the command line to that shell:

```
bash -c "echo $PATH"
```

Try this to understand what I mean, then use this:

```
bash -c "ps axu | grep PATTERN"
```

to understand how you need to set up your java.runtime.Process.

I did not try it but I assume this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", "ps axu | grep PATTERN" });
```

Hope that helps ;D

Comment: That was not working for me... After reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375711/more-elegant-ps-aux-grep-v-grep), I finally decide to use pgrep instead of grep

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to separate the command from its arguments when calling exec, eg `.exec(new String[] { "ps", "aux" })` (*not* `exec("ps aux")`). When you need to pass arguments, you need to invoke the String[] version - the first element of the `String[]` is the command, the rest are the arguments.
2. You need to send the contents of the output stream of the first command to the input stream of the second command. I used [Apache commons IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) to do this with ease.
3. You must close the input stream of the `grep` call, otherwise it will hang waiting for the end of input.

With these changes in place, this code does what you want:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ps", "aux" });
    InputStream input = p1.getInputStream();
    Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "grep", "java" });
    OutputStream output = p2.getOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(input, output);
    output.close(); // signals grep to finish
    List<String> result = IOUtils.readLines(p2.getInputStream());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Is that a deadlock hazard when single-threaded?  Could use `PumpStreamHandler` from commons-exec.

Comment: Fair comment. I was trying to keep this as simple as possible to illustrate to important bits. Caution: May deadlock in single-thread environments.

Comment: I wish the JDK provided the equivalent of `IOUtils.copy`. This is where other languages are more appealing for some programs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I do not know how to correctly pipe results from one command to another, but if all you want is the Java process, the JDK comes with a program called `jps` that does exactly this. Try this:

```
jps -l
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the command, it produces the list that contains PID, Process Name. What i am looking to get PID %CPU %MEM  VSZ RSS TTY & COMMAND.