# More elegant "ps aux | grep -v grep"

Tags: linux, grep

When I check list of processes and 'grep' out those that are interesting for me, the `grep` itself is also included in the results. For example, to list terminals:

```
$ ps aux  | grep terminal
user  2064  0.0  0.6 181452 26460 ?        Sl   Feb13   5:41 gnome-terminal --working-directory=..
user  2979  0.0  0.0   4192   796 pts/3    S+   11:07   0:00 grep --color=auto terminal
```

Normally I use `ps aux | grep something | grep -v grep` to get rid of the last entry... but it is not *elegant* :)

Do you have a more elegant hack to solve this issue (apart of wrapping all the command into a separate script, which is also not bad)

Comment: For what it's worth, this is an ancient FAQ.  See item 3.10 at http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/

Comment: Thanks for reference. That's their method: `ps ux | awk '/name/ && !/awk/ {print $2}'`

Comment: What is the `grep -v grep` part doing?

Comment: @Jwan622 `grep -v grep` excludes `grep` from grep results. If grep is used in combination with ps, then grep process (with grep arguments) will be shown as well, cluttering your results. grep -v grep is a common way to avoid that

Answer (score 292, accepted):

The usual technique is this:

```
ps aux | egrep '[t]erminal'
```

This will match lines containing `terminal`, which `egrep '[t]erminal'` does not! It also works on ***many*** flavours of Unix.

Comment: This works for me for an arbitrary string, but not for a username, e.g. `ps aux | grep '[r]oot'` . Does anyone know why?

Comment: @kxsong: `| grep '[t]erminal'` selects any line containing the word 'terminal' without putting the word 'terminal' into the process list. What are you trying to achieve with `| grep '[r]oot'` and how is it not working? There is likely to be a better solution.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this also should work on any position of the grepped character: ps aux| grep "te[r]minal"

Comment: brilliant hack (I think I should call it that, since the aux / grep authors probably did not think of this scenario.)

Comment: Would you please explain how this works? I understand regular expressions, but I don't see how putting t in a character class excludes the grep process itself.

Comment: @JamieJag: Well... like I said in my post, `grep '[t]erminal'` will match lines containing `terminal`. The output from `ps aux` will have a line with `grep '[t]erminal'` (with the square brackets), which does not contain the string `terminal` (without the same).

Comment: @MichaelTrouw:I'm pretty sure this hack is quite old (I think I remember seing it mentionned in some Usenet faq, back in the "old days" (circa 95? which is not at all around the creation of grep, but that hack may be quite older too)

Comment: Could also escape an internal character, like `ps aux | grep 't\erminal'` or `ps aux | grep t\\erminal`. And there you go, saved all that typing. ;-)

Answer (score 60):

Use [pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep). It's more reliable.

Comment: `pgrep` wont work if I look for example for `ps aux | grep 'ssh options'`

Comment: Jakub M.: What about `pgrep -f` ?

Comment: @jakub-m By default `pgrep` only matches the pattern against the process name. To match against the entire command, use the `-f` flag.

Comment: I have posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25372044/832230) which builds upon this answer, combining `pgrep` with `ps`.

Comment: Note if you prefix pgrep with sudo it does not filter itself out.

Comment: `pgrep` only returns process IDs.

Comment: @Melab nope, you can get the full command line with `pgrep -a`.

Comment: @Desty Older versions of pgrep do not have the '-a' option.

Comment: older versions took `pgrep -fl` (but couldn't see full cmdline without `-f` matching full cmdline, details: https://serverfault.com/a/619788/44183).  But yes if you need any other info beside pid, cmdline, you need `ps`. Can combine them: `ps -p $(pgrep -f foo)`

Comment: What if I wan't to grep using more than just first [15 characters](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) of the process name (not path nor arguments)? In that case pgrep became useless. `-f` use the full command line used, not just the real complete name.

Answer (score 30):

This answer builds upon a prior `pgrep` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9375746/832230). It also builds upon another [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75726/50855) combining the use of `ps` with `pgrep`. Here are some pertinent training examples:

```
$ pgrep -lf sshd
1902 sshd

$ pgrep -f sshd
1902

$ ps up $(pgrep -f sshd)
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1902  0.0  0.1  82560  3580 ?        Ss   Oct20   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

$ ps up $(pgrep -f sshddd)
error: list of process IDs must follow p
[stderr output truncated]

$ ps up $(pgrep -f sshddd) 2>&-
[no output]
```

The above can be used as a **function**:

```
$ psgrep() { ps up $(pgrep -f $@) 2>&-; }

$ psgrep sshd
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1902  0.0  0.1  82560  3580 ?        Ss   Oct20   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Compare with using `ps` with `grep`. The useful header row is not printed:

```
$  ps aux | grep [s]shd
root      1902  0.0  0.1  82560  3580 ?        Ss   Oct20   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Comment: See https://github.com/blueyed/oh-my-zsh/blob/a08181210b47625efdc8480e628b0155bff392c9/lib/aliases.zsh#L10-L18 (but it's specific to Zsh).

Comment: @blueyed, I have updated the answer with the bash function definition.

Comment: Note also `-d` option to specify a separator; e.g. `ps -fp$(pgrep -d , getty)`

Comment: I use this: ``ps uxp `pgrep <process>` `` Note that `p` must be the last parameter (i.e., `pux` won't work)

Comment: This does not color the search process name like `grep` does

Answer (score 10):

You can filter in the ps command, e.g.

```
ps u -C gnome-terminal
```

(or search through /proc with *find* etc.)

Comment: Note that this works with GNU's ps (Linux), but not with the BSD ps.

Comment: This is incorrect even with GNU ps.  `ps -C <command>` will match the exact command.  When used with the `a` or `x` options it will report all processes, because `a` and `x` list processes _in addition_ to the set of processes matched by other means.

Comment: This works only if the process name is specified exactly. It doesn't work for a partial match, e.g. `logind` for `systemd-logind`, or to match arguments.

Answer (score 6):

One more [alternative](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/ps):

```
ps -fC terminal
```

Here the options:

```
 -f        does full-format listing. This option can be combined
           with many other UNIX-style options to add additional
           columns. It also causes the command arguments to be
           printed. When used with -L, the NLWP (number of
           threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be added. See
           the c option, the format keyword args, and the format
           keyword comm.

 -C cmdlist     Select by command name.
                This selects the processes whose executable name is
                given in cmdlist.
```

Comment: A minor drawback, and one which isn't really related to OP's question, is that this won't show you things like Tomcat, which is actually run as java with a laundry list of arguments.

Comment: `-C` option was already suggested in @Andreas Frishe's answer posted over year and a half earlier…

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this tool, but...

I'd use [px](http://github.com/walles/px):

```
~ $ px atom
  PID COMMAND          USERNAME   CPU RAM COMMANDLINE
14321 crashpad_handler walles   0.01s  0% /Users/walles/Downloads/Atom.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Resources/crashpad_handler --database=
16575 crashpad_handler walles   0.01s  0% /Users/walles/Downloads/Atom.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Resources/crashpad_handler --database=
16573 Atom Helper      walles    0.5s  0% /Users/walles/Downloads/Atom.app/Contents/Frameworks/Atom Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom Helper --type=gpu-process --cha
16569 Atom             walles   2.84s  1% /Users/walles/Downloads/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom --executed-from=/Users/walles/src/goworkspace/src/github.com/github
16591 Atom Helper      walles   7.96s  2% /Users/walles/Downloads/Atom.app/Contents/Frameworks/Atom Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom Helper --type=renderer --no-san
```

Except for finding processes with a sensible command line interface it also does a lot of other useful things, more details on [the project page](https://github.com/walles/px#vision).

Works on Linux and OS X, easily installed:

```
curl -Ls https://github.com/walles/px/raw/python/install.sh | bash
```

Comment: This is awesome!!

Answer (score 3):

Using brackets to surround a character in the search pattern excludes the `grep` process since it doesn't contain the matching regex.

```
$ ps ax | grep 'syslogd'
   16   ??  Ss     0:09.43 /usr/sbin/syslogd
18108 s001  S+     0:00.00 grep syslogd

$ ps ax | grep '[s]yslogd'
   16   ??  Ss     0:09.43 /usr/sbin/syslogd

$ ps ax | grep '[s]yslogd|grep'
   16   ??  Ss     0:09.43 /usr/sbin/syslogd
18144 s001  S+     0:00.00 grep [s]yslogd|grep
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the ultimate use case, you often want to prefer Awk instead.

```
ps aux | awk '/[t]erminal/'
```

This is particularly true when you have something like

```
ps aux | grep '[t]erminal' | awk '{print $1}'  # useless use of grep!
```

where obviously the regex can be factored into the Awk script trivially:

```
ps aux | awk '/[t]erminal/ { print $1 }'
```

But really, don't reinvent this yourself. `pgrep` and friends have been around for a long time and handle this entire problem space much better than most ad hoc reimplementations.

Answer (score -3):

Another option is to edit your `.bash_profile` (or other file that you keep bash aliases in) to create a function that greps 'grep' out of the results.

```
function mygrep {
grep -v grep | grep --color=auto $1
}

alias grep='mygrep'
```

The `grep -v grep` has to be first otherwise your `--color=auto` won't work for some reason.

This works if you're using bash; if you're using a different shell YMMV.

Comment: What's with the alias *and* the function?  Just do `function grep { command grep -v grep | command grep --color=auto "$@"; }` (also note the fix of the argument and the quoting).  However, this is broken in that any non-`ps` invocation of `grep` will no longer work (the arguments are passed incorrectly).  Anyway, a much more useful function would be one which modifies the regex to make it not match itself, rather than filter out `grep` from the `grep` results separately.  And of course, inventing new solutions to a problem which was adequately solved decades ago is not very productive.