# How does ps aux | grep '[p]attern' exclude grep itself?

Tags: command-line, grep, ps

The title says it all. I've seen this idiom used alot instead of adding an additional `grep -v grep` in some `ps` pipeline. For example it could be used like this:

```
$ ps aux | grep '[f]irefox' | awk '{ print $8 }'
```

instead of

```
$ ps aux | grep 'firefox' | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $8 }'
```

It's super-convenient, but how does it work and why?

Comment: You do not need `grep`, just use `ps aux | awk '/[f]irefox/ {print $8}'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [More elegant "ps aux | grep -v grep"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375711/more-elegant-ps-aux-grep-v-grep)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `[f]irefox` will not match the literal string `[f]irefox`. Instead it will match strings with exactly one char from the 1-character class `[f]`, followed by `irefox`.