# ps pipe to grep brackets grep keyword.

Tags: grep, ps, square-bracket

A lot of times when I use ps and pipe it into grep, I put one of the grep characters in [ ] square brackets. I do this do the actual call to grep is not included in the ps readout. It helps when I am scripting. Like if I redirect the output to a file, and that file is empty, the process I am looking at is not on. I do not know why bracketing one character of the grep works, and was amused to see that using the brackets is actually faster and takes less processing time.

```
-bash-3.2$ time ps -ef | grep *.[j]il

real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.017s

-bash-3.2$ time ps -ef | grep *.jil
zksuy7k  11528 18285  0 20:54 pts/7    00:00:00 grep *.jil   

real    0m0.040s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.016s
-bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Is your question "what is the bracket for and why is it apparently faster"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does ps aux | grep '\[p\]attern' exclude grep itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528894/how-does-ps-aux-grep-pattern-exclude-grep-itself)

Comment: Also, is it consistently faster? You have just one measurement each.