# Difference between ps | grep safe and ps | grep safe\$

Tags: linux, grep, openwrt

```
# ps  | grep safe
14592 root      136m S    /tmp/data/safe/safe
16210 root      1664 S    grep safe

# ps  | grep safe\$
14592 root      258m S    /tmp/data/safe/safe
```

So what does `\$` mean? Is it a regular expression?

Comment: Thanks for your detaill answer.From my understanding bash$ means The string end with bash,that's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a regex. `$` is a regex character that means "end of line". So by saying `grep safe\$` you are `grep`ping all those lines whose name ends with `safe` and avoiding `grep` itself to be part of the output.

The thing here is that if you run the `ps` command and `grep` its output, the `grep` itself will be listed:

```
$ ps -ef | grep bash
me       30683  9114  0 10:25 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
me       30722  8859  0 10:33 pts/3    00:00:00 grep bash
```

So by saying `grep safe\$`, or its equivalent `grep "safe$"`, you are adding a regular expression in the match that will make the `grep` itself to not show.

```
$ ps -ef | grep "bash$"
me       30683  9114  0 10:25 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
```

As a funny situation, if you use the `-F` option in `grep`, it will match exact string, so the only output you will get is the `grep` itself:

```
$ ps -ef | grep -F "bash$"
me       30722  8859  0 10:33 pts/3    00:00:00 grep -F bash$
```

The typical trick to do this is `grep -v grep`, but you can find others in [More elegant "ps aux | grep -v grep"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9375711/1983854). I like the one that says `ps -ef | grep "[b]ash"`.