# Why does grep return different results when regex is used?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, grep

```
> ps -ef | grep cron

root      1052     1  0 04:35 ?        00:00:00 cron
test   4071  4053  0 10:15 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cron

> ps -ef | grep cr[o]n

root      1052     1  0 04:35 ?        00:00:00 cron
```

Why do these two commands return different results when the search term is equivalent?

Comment: if you failed to put the regex inside quotes, then it would be interpolated by shell

Comment: Thanks. How does that change things?Even if there are interpolated by the shell, why are the results different?

Comment: This is an ancient FAQ. Did you google at all?

Comment: Of course I did. Try assuming some positive intent. Can you recommend some terms I could search for that might yield me some better results?

Comment: @vrjr What Avinash is saying is that if there is a file named `cron` in the current directory, the shell will perform wildcard expansion on the argument `cr[o]n`, turning it into `cron` before `grep` sees it. This would make your example unreproducible under these circumstances. The lesson here is to always quote your regexes.

Comment: @tripleee That's very insightful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Linked (possible duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/9375711/2088135

Comment: See my response, you are all wrong.  The response doesn't depend on the grep command, but on the presence of the `grep` command in the system when the `ps(1)` gathers the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the second case the processes running actually are (altough the second you cannot see after the grep filter is applied):

```
root      1052     1  0 04:35 ?        00:00:00 cron
test   4071  4053  0 10:15 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cr[o]n
```

And `cr[o]n` is not matched by `cr[o]n` as `[o]` specifies the list of characters `o`, while the real string contains also `[` and `]` around the `o`.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
> ps -ef | grep cron
```

matches the string "cron" in the command, giving you

```
test   4071  4053  0 10:15 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

However, the command

```
> ps -ef | grep cr[o]n
```

does NOT match the string "cr[o]n" in the command itself, omitting it from the result.

Answer (score -1):

Not to all, if you repeat the command several times, the output will be different for both classes of commands.  The reason is that the output depends on the grep command being in execution at the time the ps gets the info.  Bash shell just launches both commands in quick sequence, but sometimes the `ps(1)` command gets the info when `bash(1)` has not had time yet to launch the `grep(1)` one.

Both regexps are completely equivalent as `cr[o]n` is exactly the same as `cron`.

Make a test launching several times `ps -ef | grep grep` and see that sometimes the grep command appears and sometimes not.

Comment: The regexes are not completely equivalent; `cr[o]n` does not match itself.

Comment: Ok, you are right, but I'm right also, if you don't believe me, just execute several times the command and you'll see I'm right.  And I have not downvoted you for that reason.