# How do I start application if it stopped using Cron?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Debian 8.6. No root.
I can use cron.
I need to check if application ( php ./somescript & ) running in background stopped, and restart it. How can I check it using bash?
Of course, there is ps aux | grep ....., but how do I automate it?

Comment: I suggest to start your application this way then there is no need to check and restart: `while true; do php /path/to/somescript; done`

Comment: Does it create a PID file that indicates it's running? Could you use a launcher to manage it via `systemctl`? Would a tool like [PHP-Daemon](https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon) do the trick?

Comment: @Cyrus That's a really heavy-handed way of launching things and it won't work post-reboot.

Comment: this script is already a daemon, but if my shared-hosting is restarting - daemon doesn't start. I need a script that checks if script is not working, then launches it

Comment: For non-bash daemons, the best way is to use a lock file.  The first step in the daemon should be to lock the file and proceed only upon being able to lock successfully.  This is better than the PID file logic.

Comment: @tadman, why would you describe the while loop as "heavy-handed"? That's exactly the concept employed (plus a bit of error checking) by system tools like `init` or `systemd`. The loop takes no extra processing unless the process needs to be restarted. Much lighter weight than running a check script in cron every minute or five.

Comment: @ghoti Cron's pretty good at what it does, and for the 99% of the time this script isn't running it's not using any memory. A daemonized PHP script *will* need to be started manually on boot. A cron job won't, it'll keep going after any number of reboots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to take a look at keyword `@reboot` from `man 5 crontab` to start a job once at server startup.

Comment: This is a nice & clean approach, but it does not test if the application is running on the background as asked on the question `I need to check if application ( php ./somescript & ) running in background [has] stopped, and restart it`. Also, if the application stops during "normal" usage (not due to a reboot), this solution will not restart the application.

Comment: Okay, I suggest `@reboot while true; do /path/to/php /path/to/somescript; done` as cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it would be:

Cron:

```
* * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /folder/myscript >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The `env DISPLAY=:0` might not be needed in your case, or it might be needed, depending on your script (note: you might need to adapt this to your case, run `echo $DISPLAY` to find out your variable on the case).

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
testvar="$(ps aux | grep -s "somescript" | grep -sv "grep")"
if [ -z "$testvar" ]; then nohup /folder/somescript &; fi
exit 0
```

This all could and should be fine tuned to your needs, but I believe this example could serve you well.

**Edit:** I fixed a small oversight on the code (I added `| grep -sv "grep"` to get rid of the own grep process of looking for the file from the `tesvar` results).

Comment: I suggest to replace `"somescript"` by `"[s]omescript"`.

Comment: Why? Please enlighten me.

Comment: See: [More elegant “ps aux | grep -v grep”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9375711/3776858)

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. I forgot that using `grep` on this context would create a process on its own that would interfere with the results - I fixed my answer. However, I went with the traditional  `grep -sv` construction because I fear of compatibility issues. But your tip was really appreciated, i did not know of this approach.