# ps command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, echo, ps

I'm a newbie to unix-like.  And I met a weird issue that I really cannot find answers by searching.

```
#!/bin/bash
me=`basename "$0"`
echo $(ps -e | grep "$me" | wc -l)
ps -e | grep "$me" | wc -l
```

After executing that bash script, the echo shows me 2, and ps just shows me 1 which is what I want.  How can this happen?  Why echo shows me an extra process?

Comment: See: [More elegant “ps aux | grep -v grep”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9375711/3776858)

Comment: `$()` creates a subshell -- a forked-off copy of your shell. So while you're running `echo $(ps -e | grep "$me" | wc -l)`, there are *actually* more processes running that match your expression.

Comment: That said, grepping through `ps` is absolutely bad practice, and should not be done for any kind of automated use. While there are tools such as `pgrep` and such that work around some of the caveats, if your intent is to determine whether a program is already running, there are far better ways to do it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Charles Duffy pointed out, `$() creates a subshell`.  That answers my question.  Apparently I still have a lot to learn.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by a comment by Cyrus; this script:

```
me=$(basename $0)
ps -ef |grep $me
```

when launched with "./ps.sh", prints:

```
auser@pc:/tmp$ ./ps.sh
auser     4425  4422  0 08:42 pts/3    00:00:00 grep ps.sh
auser@pc:/tmp$
```

No subshells are involved here, it is the grep(1) itself that is listed by ps(1). The same script, launched with "bash ps.sh" outputs:

```
auser     4426  3946  0 08:44 pts/3    00:00:00 bash ps.sh
auser     4429  4426  0 08:44 pts/3    00:00:00 grep ps.sh
```

This is the result the OP gets, even without subshells. Even more explicit:

```
auser@pc:/tmp$ ps -ef |grep grep
auser     4467  3946  0 08:49 pts/3    00:00:00 grep grep
```

Answer (score 0):

although you are creating a sub shell by using `$()` you can grep this out by using `grep -v grep`.

So:

```
$(ps -e | grep "$me" | grep -v grep | wc -l)
```

which will return 1 instead of 2