# Write a command to kill first process whose name contains "ca"? Only first process having "ca" in its’ name must be killed, not others?

Tags: linux, bash

new to linux and am trying to learn more of it, and i came accross this situation.

i have tried by using ps command and using grep to catch "ca" but it returns every occurence of "ca" no matter what it is from and it doesn't actually help me.

i have tried this solution but it won't work

```
ps aux | grep ca
find out the process id
and issue kill <process number>
```

but grep will catch all "ca" no matter where it is, in process name, directory and anything.

what should i do to achieve what i need. thanks in advance

Comment: There is no guarantee that the first process with matching "ca" will always be the process you want. Please say what is your exact requirement

Comment: You can check `pgrep` command for your purpose.

Comment: @Niati Arora:I recommend taking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9375711/3776858) into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
pkill -o ca
```

The `-o` option to `pkill` kills the oldest matching process. To get the newest, use the `-n` option:

```
pkill -n ca
```

Note `pkill` takes a pattern, so if you want to get the process that *starts* with "ca" you can do that as well:

```
pkill -o ^ca
```

Comment: Wraparound happens. PIDs get recycled. "First in the table" may *usually* be oldest, but it's not by any means *always* oldest.

Comment: Excellent point; visiting the man page gave a better solution anyway!

Comment: Much better indeed. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 kill `ps -aux | sed "s/\s\+/ /g" | cut -d ' ' -f2,11 | sed "s/ .*\// /g" | grep ca | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1`
```

1. Use cut to extract pid and command name from ps
2. Strip path from command name.
3. Grep for ca
4. Select 1st result only
5. Select pid column only
6. Pass pid as first argument to kill