# Bash comparison between numbers fail

Tags: bash

I think I'm missing something with variable types...why the following script, that is supposed to read a number of lines and compare this number to 1 always enters the if even though it returns exactly 1?

```
status() {
lines=`ps aux | grep myprocess | wc -l` #returns 1 
if [ $lines -gt 1 ]; then
  echo "Process is up"
else
  echo "Process is down"
fi
}
```

Comment: How do you know it returns exactly 1?

Comment: ...it doesn't, I tried an echo. How is this possible? If I do that in bash it returns 1, but in that script it returns 4

Comment: Try `output=$(ps aux | grep myprocess); printf 'Results:\n%s\n' "$output"` and see what the found lines are.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9375711/3776858

Comment: `pgrep` avoids the need for a separate grep, and also ensures that it itself is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using melpomene's suggestion to use egrep instead of grep.
Strangely enough that command had several lines printed when ran as init script.