# Shell script to stop the tomcat service if elasticsearch service in also stopped

Tags: sh, ubuntu-18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04LTS and I have two small situation

1. I want to write a script that will check if elasticsearch service is not running then that script will also stop the tomcat service.
2. Also I want to run the script in every 5 second.

I can achieve the 2nd task by using the crontab but here is a small twist, I want to hold the crontab script for the 30 seconds when the system boots/reboot(because elasticsearch service takes a little time to get start).

I think I cannot use sleep here because then it will delay the execution every time for 30 second.

For the 1st task the script I am using now is:

```
#!/bin/sh
command = $(/bin/ps -ef|/bin/grep -c /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid)
if [ ${command} == 1 ];
then
    service tomcat stop
fi
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
./myscript.sh: 2: ./myscript.sh: =: not found
./myscript.sh: 3: [: ==: unexpected operator
```

**UPDATE-1:**

My first script is running but not working properly means it stops the tomcat service even if the elasticsearch service is ruuning, but I want to write a script that will stop the tomcat service only if elasticsearch service is not running.

**I sure this is some kind of logical error.**

```
#!/bin/sh
command=$(/bin/ps -ef|/bin/grep -c /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid)
echo $command
if [$command=1];
then
    echo "ok"
fi
```

Getting the error:

```
./myscript.sh: 4: ./myscript.sh: [2=1]: not found
```

**UPDATE-2:** I changed my if statement and it worked

```
if [ "$command" = 1 ];
```

**Now does anyone how to solve the 2nd situation.**

Comment: No spaces around `=`.

Comment: `[` doesn’t have a `==` operator. You probably want `=`.

Comment: Note that your shebang says `sh` but you’ve tagged the question with Bash. They are not (quite) the same.

Comment: (There’s not really any reason to use a variable and `grep -c`; `if ps -ef | grep -q ...` would suffice.)

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.

Comment: @Biffen, I don't need tomcat status I just want to stop it only if elasticsearch service is stopped.

Comment: Never mind my last comment (now deleted). I misunderstood.

Comment: `ps|grep` seems brittle. If you know Elasticsearch’s PID file, wouldn’t it be more reliable to inspect it directly?

Comment: The `[` command _does_ want spaces around `=`.

Comment: @Biffen, I changed the script as you suggested but the error is this:

`./myscript.sh: 4: ./myscript.sh: [2==1]: not found`

Comment: The `if` line should be `if [ "$command" = 1 ]`. Once again; [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.

Comment: @Biffen, Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [More elegant "ps aux | grep -v grep"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375711/more-elegant-ps-aux-grep-v-grep)